# Only some of my programs can connect to my SVN using the same information

Tags: svn, netbeans, ssh, tortoisesvn

I have a svn server with repositories on it that I haven't touch in about 6 months. I decided I would clean them out and add them to the new computer I have. I went to use the same info that is saved in tortoise svn on all my computers for the repositories and I get the error.

- Error Unable to connect to a repository at URL List item
- Error 'svn+ssh://192.168.1.6/var/svn-repos/Documentation
- Error Can't create tunnel: The system cannot find the file specified.

I then went to my server to check what was going on but using the same information locally I was able to connect. I then tried the svn tools for Netbeans and it was able to commit to the server using the same info. I then tried cleaning out the save info for tortoise using the settings tool and putting the info in again but still go this error. I am really stumped as to why every other program I have could connect except tortoise svn.

Comment: If it s been moved, possibe SSH identifiers have changed which could prevent a SSH connection. Have you tried clearing `"%APPDATA%\Subversion\auth`? Note that will remove ALL your stored authentication.

Comment: @Wrikken I cleaned that folder out and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @Wrikken It still seems to be storing the information some where because it repopulates that folder with the info from before after I start tortoise again.

Comment: Hm, and your SSH client (usually Putty), has that one stored anything?

Comment: Under the config file in the subversion folder on the client machine I have this line ssh = $SVN_SSH ssh -o ControlMaster=no does that look correct?

Comment: @Wrikken Yeah my Putty has the same info stored.

Comment: I'm more interested what (1) $SVN_SSH is (I still assume Putty) and (2) where Putty stores its known host fingerprints). Have you tried to connect with plain SSH to your server & does that give any (more detailed) errors?

Comment: @Wrikken I can get into the server fine via SSH and then from there I can run any SVN commands I want with no problems. Only when using Tortoise do I get any errors. The $SVN_SSH is from the config file in %APPDATA%\Subversion. Yeah I am using Putty but I have also used another linux machine to SSH in as well.

Comment: Aight, then I'm stumped.

Comment: @Wrikken you helped me find the answer although I have no idea why it fixed it or how both computers got this setting changed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem thanks to @Wrikkens again thank you for leading me to the folder that contained the problem. For some reason the subversion config file for Tortoise SVN stored at %APPDATE%\Subverion had the line ssh = $SVN_SSH ssh -o ControlMaster=no uncommented. I commented the line and it worked fine. Although it does ask me for my password like 4 times and if anyone could help me with that it would be appreciated.